# How to crop the Image using Python PIL or CV?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

My all images have Region of interest which is bounded by doted white lines.
I want to crop only those portion.

I got one idea that find minimum(x,y) which is top left corner and find maximum(x,y) which is bottom right corner and crop the area?

We can get Pixel value from PIL library

Comment: Maybe you would care to show us your image so we don't have to guess what you mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from IPython.display import Image as displayImage 
img=Image.open('image.png')
imag_rgb = img.convert('RGB')
width, height = imag_rgb.size
print (width, height)
for pixel_x in range(width):
 for pixel_y in range(height):
  r, g, b = rgb_img.getpixel((pixel_x, pixel_y))
  if(r == 255 and g == 255 and b == 255):
   min_pixel_x = pixel_x
   min_pixel_y = pixel_y
   max_pixel_x = pixel_x
   max_pixel_y = pixel_y                
   print (pixel_x, pixel_y)
    cropped_image = img.crop((min_pixel_x, min_pixel_y,max_pixel_x + 1, max_pixel_y + 1))
#### +1 because of first x,y is 0,0
display(cropped_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to crop images using opencv2. Try this link

http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html

```
ball = img[280:340, 330:390]
```

since Image is a 2D array you can crop with above line.

Answer (score 0):

To read a pixel value in PIL

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(imagename)
pix = im.load()
print (pix[0,0])
```

This will return the first pixel in the first row.

If you wanted to read all pixels you could do something like this.

```
x, y = im.size

for i in x:
    for j in y:
        print (pix[i,j])
```

Comment: This is not a good way to do it. Avoid for loops, they are slow. Slicing should be prefered. See other answers.